# Having an SQL SELECT query, how do I get number of items?

Tags: perl, sqlite, dbi

I'm writing a web app in Perl using Dancer framework. The database is in sqlite and I use DBI for database interaction.

I'm fine with select statements, but I wonder is there a way to count selected rows.

E.g. I have

```
get '/' => sub {
    my $content = database->prepare(sprintf("SELECT * FROM content LIMIT %d",
            $CONTNUM));
    $content->execute;
    print(Dumper($content->fetchall_arrayref));
};
```

How do I count all items in the result without issuing another query?

What I want to achieve this way is showing 30 items per page and knowing how many pages there would be. Of course I can run SELECT COUNT (*) foo bar, but it looks wrong and redundant to me. I'm looking for a more or less general, DRY and not too heavy on database way to do so.

Any SQL or Perl hack or a hint what should I read about would be appreciated.

// I know using string concatenation for querys is bad

Comment: What's wrong with `SELECT COUNT(*)`?  If you have a very large table, it won't fit into memory.  Select the count and then each record one at a time is a pattern people are use to seeing.  I recommend that you use it unless you have a reason not to.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to do it the hard way: one query to get the count and another to get your desired slice of the row set:

```
my $count = $database->prepare('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM content');
$count->execute();
my $n = $count->fetchall_arrayref()->[0][0];

my $content = $database->prepare('SELECT * FROM content LIMIT ?');
$content->execute($CONTNUM);
#...
```

Comment: I think this might be the only way too... at least for SQLite.

Comment: Hard way is OK as long as it's correcct, I just thougth that subs become suspiciously long like that and decided to check if anything can be done. Thank you.

Comment: @Roman: Then you can put the SQL in a string and append the `LIMIT ?` part for the second query or wrap both in a sub sort of like `($n, $results) = count_and_results($sql, $limit)` and the sub would worry about appending the `LIMIT ?` for the second query.

Comment: I'll see what would turn out to be more readable - the example in the question is actually the most simple one.

Comment: @Roman: there are [tricks for MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/information-functions.html#function_found-rows) that will let you do it with one statement. Just an FYI in case you also use MySQL somewhere.

Comment: Yes, I'm planning to try MySQL for something bigger after I finish this one. Thnx.

Comment: For some reason, `@{$count->fetchall_arrayref()}[0]` didn't work for me, but `$count->fetchall_arrayref->[0]->[0]` did. I don't know why, but maybe it will be useful to someone else.

Comment: @gnobal: `fetchall_arrayref` returns an AoA not just an A so you have to unwrap two arrays rather than just one. `fetchall_arrayref->[0][0]` is probably the cleanest but there's nothing wrong with using two `->` to help you keep your references straight. Thanks for catching that.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up, @muistooshort . I'm new to perl and learning on the go using answers like yours :)

Answer (score 1):

Not too familiar with perl, but I assume you can just store the result of `$content->fetchall_arrayref` and retrieve the count from that array befor you print it.

[edit]

Something like

```
my $ref = $content->fetchall_arrayref;
my $count = scalar(@$ref);
```

Comment: It's not quite what I'm trying to get. It would return $CONTNUM which I already know because it would count the number of items in the slice, and I would like to get the total number of items fitting the query, like select - count - slice.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use sqlite myself but the following might work:

```
select * from table join (select count(*) from table);
```

Whether the above works or not the first thing I'd look for is scrollable cursors if you are going to page through results - I doubt sqlite has those. However, in DBI you can use fetchall_arrayref with a max_rows to fetch a "page" at a time. Just look up the example in the DBI docs under fetchall_arrayref - it is something like this:

```
my $rowcache = [];
while( my $row = ( shift(@$rowcache) || shift(@{$rowcache=$sth->fetchall_arrayref(undef,100)||[]}) )
         ) {
           # do something here
         }
```

UPDATE: Added what you'd get with selectall_hashref assuming the table is called content with one integer column called "a":

```
$ perl -le 'use DBI; my $h = DBI->connect("dbi:SQLite:dbname=fred.db"); my $r = $h->selectall_hashref(q/select * from content join (select count(*) as count from content)/, "a");use Data::Dumper;print Dumper($r);'
$VAR1 = {
          '1' => {
                   'count' => '3',
                   'a' => '1'
                 },
          '3' => {
                   'count' => '3',
                   'a' => '3'
                 },
          '2' => {
                   'count' => '3',
                   'a' => '2'
                 }
        };
```

Comment: Yes, I noticed that feature in reference. I used `arrayref` for prototype of some sort (along with `Data::Dumper`) to see if things work on mapping url to query level. For actual page rendering I picked `hashref` which seems to fit into `TT` in more readable way (using keys instead of element indices) but does not provide this slicing functionality. I'll look at cursors later when I'll start playing with 'serious' SQL. Will also try the `join` trick. I wonder if it would work well in the context, I mean, I need to see a hash which `DBI` would make out of it.

Comment: Oh, you really didn't have to do it at all! I meant *I* must run it and see. Sorry for that.

Comment: no problem, I've not really used SQLite so I thought it was semi interesting.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know how many results there will be, as well as getting the results themselves, all in one query, then get the count as a new value:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS num_rows, * from Table WHERE ...
```

Now the row count will be the first column of every row of your resultset, so simply pop that off before presenting the data.

Comment: That won't work, you'll get one row with the count at the front rather than `$CONTNUM` rows with the count at the front. At least that's what the `sqlite3` shell does.

Comment: ... and an error to the effect that a GROUP BY clause is missing.

Comment: I don't think you'll get an error that GROUP BY is missing. Why would you need a GROUP BY just to do a count(*). What you will get in sqlite is as "mu is too short" describes - one row.

Comment: In some databases you would get an error to the effect that a 'group by' is missing. In sqlite, you'll get what 'mu is too short' describes.